# ¿Cómo calcular el tiempo transcurrido de un evento tomando en cuenta el cambio de hora?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

He echo un script que elimina todos los archivos de una carpeta pasados 5 minutos desde el momento en el que fueron creados o modificados por última vez.

Tomando en cuenta la eventualidad de que algún archivo sea creado en el momento del cambio de la zona horaria, implementé unas condiciones que se aseguran de que el archivo sea eliminado igualmente en el arco de esos 5 minutos.
El método que usé es efectivo, pero supe por un programador de más experiencia que existe una forma más eficaz, probablemente usando alguna librería o algún método de `datetime` che no conozco.

Soy amante del código limpio y me gustaría conocer este otro método para seguir mejorando profesionalmente. De antemano, gracias.

Aquí les dejo la parte del código que concierne al asunto:

```
# fTime es la fecha de ultima modificacion del archivo
# fPath es el directorio y nombre completo del archivo

now = datetime.now()  # Obtiene hora actual

if now > fTime:
    diff = now - fTime  # Actua normalmente o cuando el tiempo va arriba de 1 o 2 horas en la zona horaria
else:
    diff = fTime - now  # Actua cuando el tiempo va atras de 1 o 2 horas en la zona horaria

minutes = diff.seconds / 60  # Transforma horas en minutos

if 55 < minutes < 65:  # Arregla el tiempo si cambia de 1 o mas horas adelante o atras
    fixTime = 60 - minutes
    if -5 > fixTime > 5:  # Elimina archivo con diferencia de 5 minutos adelante o atras respecto a la hora actual
        remove(fPath)
else:  # Si no hay cambios en la zona horaria el control pasa por aqui
    if minutes > 5:  # Elimina los archivos con 5 minutos de diferencia adelante respecto a la hora actual
        remove(fPath)
```

Comment: ¿No hay posibilidades de operar todo en UTC/GMT?

Comment: No sabría, ¿Cómo se hace para obtener la fecha de creación de un archivo en UTC/GMT?  Creo que el archivo te dirá siempre la hora en base a la que tiene el sistema que lo hospeda.

Comment: No tengo idea como se guardan internamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pesar de que nos es imposible saber la manera a la que se refería tu experimentado colega, te compartiré lo que yo haría. De esta manera, de acuerdo a lo que tengo entendido de cómo funciona el mundo, los problemas de cambio de zona horaria son indiferentes.

Lo que yo haría sería basarme en el [tiempo Unix](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix), o POSIX, el cual es agnóstico de zonas horarias en el sentido de que este mide los segundos transcurridos desde el primer segundo del 1 de enero de 1970 (UTC).

Así pues, aprovechando que Python nos permite obtener la información, o metadata, de un archivo a través de la función `lstat` del módulo `os`, y que dentro de esta información viene incluido el momento en que se creó el archivo dado en tiempo Unix, podemos entonces simplificar el algoritmo que has creado.

Aunado a esto, podemos obtener el tiempo Unix actual a través del método `time()` del módulo `time`.

Considerando todo lo anterior, podemos escribir lo siguiente:

```
from os import lstat
from time import time


file_path = '/home/directory/whatever.txt'
file_metadata = lstat(file_path)

current_unix_time = time()
file_creation_unix_time = file_metadata.st_ctime
minutes_elapsed =  (current_unix_time - file_creation_unix_time) / 60

if minutes_elapsed > 5:
    remove(file_path)
```

**Actualización:** Me acabo de percatar que dices "creado o modificado". En ese caso, puedes acceder al valor que deseas a través de `file_metadata.st_mtime`.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muchas gracias! ¿Sabes si el método `st_mtime` en caso de que el archivo no haya sido modificado desde su creación contiene la fecha de creación?

Comment: Ya lo revisé, en caso de que no haya sido modificado `st_mtime` equivale a la fecha de creación.